# Unable to create instance of entity framework object using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection, activator

I am trying to create an instance of an Entity Framework object using reflection:

```
var type = Type.GetType("MyAssembly.MyEntityNamespace.MyEntity");
var target = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

I have used this code before and it has always worked great on "regular" objects but when I use it on EF objects in this solution, `GetType()` returns null. My EF model is in its own separate project and this code is executing in its own unit testing assembly. The test assembly *does* reference the EF assembly and the EF assembly is making it into the /bin.

I can create instance of the EF classes normally but even this attempt at reflection does not work:

```
var item = new MyEntity();               //works fine
Type.GetType(item.GetType().FullName);   //null
Type.GetType(item.GetType().Name);       //null
```

I'm not sure if this is an EF thing or a project reference thing. Why aren't I able to create a new instance of this object using simple reflection when I can create the object so easily without reflection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the EF context is in a different assembly, you'll need to provide the assembly-qualified name, rather than just the namespace and typename.

The assembly-qualified name looks something like this:

```
"MyAssembly.MyEntityNamespace.MyEntity, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```

If you are using System.Web, there is also a BuildManager class that has some utilities for more easily identifying classes based on their name:

```
Type type = BuildManager.GetType("MyAssembly.MyEntityNamespace.MyEntity", false, true);
```

Comment: That seems obvious now that you mention it. I'll give it a shot and respond back a little later.

Comment: That was it. It didnt like the fully qualified name with version, culture and public key token, but `MyAssembly.MyNamespace.MyEntity, MyAssembly` worked. Thanks so much!